# Users don't appear in /etc/passwd on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix

By examining the `/etc/passwd` file, I should get a list of all users in the system. However, when dumping the `passwd` file on Mac OS X I don't see my current username but many entries like these:

```
  _xgridagent:*:86:86:Xgrid Agent:/var/xgrid/agent:/usr/bin/false
  _appowner:*:87:87:Application Owner:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
  _windowserver:*:88:88:WindowServer:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
  _spotlight:*:89:89:Spotlight:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
  _tokend:*:91:91:Token Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

How come I can log into the shell with my username and see that username when I do `who`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `/etc/passwd` file is only consulted when the OS is in single-user mode. The "standard" location for account information on OS X is the DirectoryService.

Try `man DirectoryService` for more information.

The following comment block appears at the top of my password file:

```
##
# User Database
# 
# Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
# in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
# Open Directory.
#
# This file will not be consulted for authentication unless the BSD local node
# is enabled via /Applications/Utilities/Directory Utility.app
# 
# See the DirectoryService(8) man page for additional information about
# Open Directory.
##
```

In recent versions of OS X Directory Utility has been moved to `/System/Library/CoreServices/Directory Utility`.

Comment: I went looking for something like that (Directory Utility) - and it isn't there in my Snow Leopard install...any idea what I could be missing - how it got there on yours?

Comment: Hmmm...[Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1532) says "_Mac OS X v10.5 includes two utilities used to bind computers to Microsoft Active Directory. Directory Utility is an application, and dsconfigad  is a command-line utility accessed through Terminal. Both may be used to configure the Active Directory connector in Directory Utility._"

Comment: It's not installed in the advertised location, nor does it appear in spotlight. Looks like my password file is lying to me.

Comment: My password file tells the same fib.  I did find `dsconfigad`.

Comment: Added the new location of directory utility.

Answer (score 11):

There is a set of Directory Services which keeps the information.  There are a series of command line tools (`dscl` for one) to manipulate them (hard) or you can use System Preferences to handle some of them.

Answer (score 4):

OS X doesn't use the UNIX/LINUX /etc/passwd files. Instead, it stores it in NetInfo. The command used to interact with NetInfo is the directory service command utility, or dscl.

I'm not familiar with the commands, but I'm sure a simple `man dscl` wouldn't hurt anyone.

Comment: NetInfo was replaced by Directory Services as of Mac OS X 10.5 and newer.

Comment: Which was replace by `opendirectoryd`.

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is not directly answering the question but I feel many who run into this question will just want to know how to do a simple query to find user information from the command line. For others along this path just needing to see similar config to the standard unix commands I found this simple command to be useful.

```
dscl . -read /Users/<putusernamehere> UniqueID PrimaryGroupID NFSHomeDirectory UserShell
```

You can also do:

```
dscl . -read /Users/<putusernamehere>
```

To see everything but be warned it will dump an hex version of the users photo to the screen.  If you need other components though its useful to see what is there if you can avoid the JPEGPhoto item.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X uses [Open Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Open_Directory).

Answer (score 1):

This will list all users included in `/etc/passwd` but also the default user missing from this.

```
dscl . list /Users
```